# How to retrieve the POST_ID

Tags: facebook, facebook-fql

Facebook posts have an unique ID. In order to use it with FQL, how can I find out what is the ID of a specific post? Thanks.

Comment: Why has my question been down voted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found that it is not possible to retrieve the id of an already existing post/object. The only way to have it seems to create the post via the graph API and store the returned value (which is the object id).